# What is more appropriate to identify a window opened via menu, outerWindowID or currentInnerWindowID?

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox-addon

I need identify windows that are opened via menu: `File > New window` in the firefox browser. MDN give us a solution in [Uniquely identifying DOM windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Windows#Uniquely_identifying_DOM_windows). Basically:

```
var util = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

var windowID1 = util.outerWindowID;
var windowID2 = util.currentInnerWindowID;

alert("outerWindowID: \t\t\t" + windowID1 + "\ncurrentInnerWindowID: \t" + windowID2);
```

Investigating the [interface definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindowUtils#Attributes):

> **currentInnerWindowID**: The ID of the window's current inner window.
>   Read only.
>   **outerWindowID**: The ID of the window's outer window. Read
>   only.

Pretty clear but still I can't decide which is more appropriate to identify a window opened via menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an extract of [Inner and outer windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Inner_and_outer_windows) (MDN article):

> > An **outer window** is a browsing context; that is, the actual
> >     environment in which a Document  is presented to the user. This may be
> >     a *window* or a *tab*, or it might be an *iframe* contained within
> >     another document. HTML5 refers to the outer window as the WindowProxy.
> >
> > An **inner window** represents the actual content being displayed;
> >     it's the current view of what the user sees.
>
> [image]
>
> As the user navigates, documents are added to the backward-forward
>   cache (often referred to as the bfcache). These are, in essence, inner
>   windows. They get displayed in the outer window, which is contained in
>   the "physical" browser window.

So as I want identify windows opened via menu that have a "physical" presence I should use **outerWindowID**.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you want the ID of the inner window - that's what you usually work with. The outer window is a construction to support [fast back/forward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching) and can be shared by multiple inner windows. I'm not sure why it was even made accessible to JavaScript.